# Adding values coming from input in js

Tags: javascript, append, addition

When I try to add several values, they just get appended.

These are my inputs (They all look the same):

```
<input type="number" id="floatOne" required>
```

This is my script:

```
<script>
function calcExactFloat(){
    var floats = new Array(document.getElementById("floatOne").value, document.getElementById("floatTwo").value,document.getElementById("floatThree").value,document.getElementById("floatFour").value,document.getElementById("floatFive").value,document.getElementById("floatSix").value,document.getElementById("floatSeven").value,document.getElementById("floatEight").value,document.getElementById("floatNine").value,document.getElementById("floatTen").value);

    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < floats.length; ++i){
        sum = sum + floats[i];
        console.log(sum);
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to parset to number    sum=sum+parseFloat(floats[i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of input elements if a string, even if that string represent a numerical value. In JavaScript, an "addition" of strings results in concatenation - `('1' + '1') === '11'`.

On order to convert the strings to numbers, the simplest way is to use a + before the variable - `+a + +b`.

Try like this:

```
var sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < floats.length; ++i){
    sum = sum + +floats[i];
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Values returned from inputs by `.value` are considered as `string` so you should to cast them to float then you can make calculation, so replace the following line :

```
sum = sum + floats[i];
```

By :

```
sum = sum + parseFloat(floats[i]);
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var floats = new Array(document.getElementById("floatOne").value, document.getElementById("floatTwo").value,document.getElementById("floatThree").value,document.getElementById("floatFour").value);

var sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < floats.length; ++i){
  sum = sum + parseFloat(floats[i]);
}

result.textContent = sum;
```

```html
<input type="number" id="floatOne" value='10'>
<input type="number" id="floatTwo" value='10'>
<input type="number" id="floatThree" value='10'>
<input type="number" id="floatFour" value='10'>
<br/>
Result : <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use parseFloat

```js
function calcExactFloat(){
    var floats = new Array(document.getElementById("floatOne").value, document.getElementById("floatTwo").value,document.getElementById("floatThree").value,document.getElementById("floatFour").value,document.getElementById("floatFive").value,document.getElementById("floatSix").value,document.getElementById("floatSeven").value,document.getElementById("floatEight").value,document.getElementById("floatNine").value,document.getElementById("floatTen").value);

    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < floats.length; i++){
 if(floats[i])
        sum = sum + parseFloat(floats[i]);
    }
 alert(sum)
 }
```

```html
 <input type="number" id="floatOne" required><br />
 <input type="number" id="floatTwo" required><br />
 <input type="number" id="floatThree" required><br />
 <input type="number" id="floatFour" required><br />
 <input type="number" id="floatFive" required><br />
 <input type="number" id="floatSix" required><br />
     <input type="number" id="floatSeven" required><br />
 <input type="number" id="floatEight" required><br />
 <input type="number" id="floatNine" required><br />
 <input type="number" id="floatTen" required><br />
  <input type="button" value="Calc" onclick="calcExactFloat()" />
```